# Why is my app behaving differently when running on AppHarbor?

Tags: c#, wcf, appharbor

I'm developing a wcf RESTful web service that uses Entity Framework and Code-First to manage a database, hosted by the SQL Server add-on in AppHarbor. Now, if I run my app locally by using Visual Studio debug that starts IIS to host the app, everything works perfectly. But if I test the service deployed (with no errors) in AppHarbor, everything goes wrong and i receive a 400 Bad Request.
this is the stack trace in the http response:

```
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
at    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7.&lt;GetResults&gt;b__6()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7.&lt;GetResults&gt;b__5()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7`2.&lt;GetInterceptorDelegate&gt;b__2(TProxy proxy, TItem item)
at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.UserCloudConn_100557DBEEC4B39F64FD7786B8E2F4080B576D2C357C3C1161822268F4233178.get_cloud()
at CloudStorageManager.MainService.GetActiveServices(UserCredential data) in d:\temp\inywl51q.z0c\input\DropboxWebService\Services\MainService.svc.cs:line 870
at CloudStorageManager.MainService.GetAvailableServices(UserCredential data) in d:\temp\inywl51q.z0c\input\DropboxWebService\Services\MainService.svc.cs:line 943
at SyncInvokeGetAvailableServices(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

For example this is my piece of code that give appharbor problems:

```
var cloudsConn = (from c in context.UserCloudConn where user.id == c.userId select c);

foreach (UserCloudConn conn in cloudsConn)
{
    list.Add(conn.cloud.name); // HERE THE STACK TRACE GIVE ME AN ERROR. LINE 870
}
```

This is the model I use:

```
public class DatabaseEntities : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseEntities() : base("name=DatabaseConnectionString") { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cloud> Clouds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserCloudConn> UserCloudConn { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string accessToken { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserCloudConn> userCloudConn { get; set; } // ogni user ha n tuple in UserCloudConn

}

public class Cloud
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string appKey { get; set; }
    public string appSecret { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserCloudConn> userCloudConn { get; set; } // ogni cloud ha n tuple in UserCloudConn
}

public class UserCloudConn
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)] 
    public int userId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)] 
    public int cloudId { get; set; }
    public string accessToken { get; set; }
    public string accessSecret { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string refreshToken { get; set; }
    public int expireIn { get; set; }
    public string tokenType { get; set; }
    public string timeStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual Cloud cloud { get; set; } // Ogni tupla in UserCloudConn è associata ad un cloud
    public virtual User user { get; set; } // Ogni tupla in UserCloudConn è associata ad uno User

}
```

**EDIT**:
I did some tests and I discovered that the problem is when I use the cloud attribute of the class UserCloudConn that is virtual. I think I should do another query with linq to get the cloud from my database, but why this doesn't work on appharbor but it works on local machine????

Comment: The stack trace shows this is a data-level concern and has nothing to do with your web-service. What is the exception type and message?

Comment: well, everything happens on AppHarbor, so I don't know what is the Exception. How can I debug it while it's on AppHarbor?

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because in local connection string I added the MultipleActiveResulSet to true, but in AppHarbor SQL server settings, I didn't activate it. So it was my fault. Now it works. Thank you